# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up'), using MakeStyle

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create custom style:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { createTheme,  } from '@mui/material/styles';


const theme = createTheme();
const widthStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    wrapper: {
       position: 'relative',
       [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: '95%'
       },
       [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            width: '75%'
       }
    }
}));

const Wrapper= () => {
    const classes = widthStyle(theme);
    return (  <div className={classes.wrapper}></div>);
}
```

However, i am getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')

Why is this happening?

My dependenceis:

```
 "@mui/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

`makeStyles` & `withStyle` are consider [legacy](https://mui.com/styles/basics/) now according to **MUI** team. Now with **MUI5** you can do it in much better way. `styled-component` already included in `@mui/material/styles` package.

You can do it in any ways or however one does it with normal `styled-component`. Please refer [here](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/) to know more.

- You can even customize MUI Component itself
- or (**new features**), put styling on the **unstyled** MUI Component options provided by MUI team ([reference](https://mui.com/customization/unstyled-components/))
- by the way, you don't have to import `createTheme` in order to use the `default theme options`. Just make sure you import `import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'` and put in your main `app.js` file ([reference](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider)).

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const Wrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'relative',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: '95%'
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
    width: '75%'
  },
  '.wrapper2': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.warning.main
  }
}));

const Wrapper= () => {
  return (  
    <Wrapper>
      Something here
      <div className="wrapper2">
        Something here too
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```